# jsx expression with conditional rendering and evaluating a value

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements, jsx

```
class AddOption extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.handleAddOption = this.handleAddOption.bind(this)
        this.state = {
            error: ''
        }
    }    
handleAddOption(e){
        e.preventDefault()

        const option = e.target.textinput.value;
         // THE FOLLOWING LINE TAKES MY OPTION AND PASSED THROUGH A METHOD 
         //COMMIG FROM PARENT IT VALUATES AND RETURNS THE RESULT
        const error =  this.props.handleAddOption(option);

        this.setState(()=>({error}))
        {!this.state.error && e.target.textinput.value =''}

    }
  render(){
        return (
            <div>
             {this.state.error && <p>{this.state.error}</p>}
            <form onSubmit={this.handleAddOption}>
            <label>textinput:</label>
            <input type="text" name="textinput"/>
            <button>Add Options</button>
            </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

1) The following code calling my handleAddOption while my form is being submited
am getting the following  error that , expected

2) I know That i can use

```
if(this.state.error){
            e.target.textinput.value = ''
        }
```

3) But i want to Know why it failed  ?

4) According to jsx we can keep any javascript expression  inside {}  so i used Assignment Expression  as second argument of my expression

5) i am thinking it will compiled to `{true && expression}` ,what did i miss and why  `{!this.state.error && e.target.textinput.value = ''}` failed

6)    `{!this.state.error && {e.target.textinput.value = ''}}` still showing me error

Comment: You should show exactly what you have and the `JSX` itself - hard to tell what the problem is without seeing it

Comment: I updated my code could you check once

Comment: Not sure I follow - why do you have `{this.state.error && e.target.textinput.value =''}` inside the `this.handleAddOption` handler?

Comment: Sorry a typo if no error then set the event value to empty string

Comment: I still don't follow. This looks like it should be a controlled `input` field rather than doing `e.target.textinput.value = ''`. Create a `state` for the value of that `input` field and manage it that way - https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html.